# Any exchange available for using virtual cards like Payoneer?

Tags: exchanges, trade, debitcard

Is there any bitcoin exchange available for trading bitcoin with virtual cards like payoneer? I know there is coinmama and locabitcoin, but they are mostly P2P. Is there something like cex.io ? Unfortunately cex doesn't support virtual cards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Coinbase](http://jle.vi/coinbase)? They accept Visa/Mastercard of all forms, I believe. Also, they're MUCH cheaper than Coinmama.

Comment: I opened an account in coinbase but later I found my country is not supported. So the buy/sell option is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a suitable one for yourself from this list https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency_exchange